# Angular 2 Observable Dataservice get item of Observable

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I am just getting started with Observables in Angular 2 and have a question.

I have a method in my data service class called getExplorerPageData which makes a http call which returns a data structure with a couple of arrays.  I would like to have an additional function called getTag which can retrieve one of the items which have been retrieved in the getExplorerPageData() call.

To be clear, I don't want to hit the server again when I call getTag, I would rather just retrieve the item from the call I already made to getExplorerPageData().

I was wondering what is the best way to do this?

```
getExplorerPageData(): Observable<IExplorerPageData> {
  return this.http.get(this.baseurl + "/explorerpagedata")
  .map((response: Response) => <IExplorerPageData>response.json())
  .catch(this.handleError);
}

getTag(id: number): ITag {
    //todo need to return one of the tags in explorerPageData.Tags
    return 
};

export interface IExplorerPageData{
 Tags: ITag[],
 Uploads: IUpload[],
}

export interface ITag {
  TagId: number,
  Title: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the call to the `.map(...)` operator or use the `do(...)` operator:

```
getExplorerPageData(): Observable<IExplorerPageData> {
  return this.http.get(this.baseurl + "/explorerpagedata")
  .map((response: Response) => {
     var data = <IExplorerPageData>response.json();
     getTag(data);
     return data;
  })
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

or

```
getExplorerPageData(): Observable<IExplorerPageData> {
  return this.http.get(this.baseurl + "/explorerpagedata")
  .map((response: Response) => <IExplorerPageData>response.json())
  .do((data) => getTag(data))
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

With the `map()` operator it's important to return the value at the end, because the returned value is what the subscriber receives.

With the `do()` operator the return value doesn't matter, the value returned from the previous `map()` is forwarded to the subscriber, no matter what `do()` returns.

Comment: I think the call to `do()` in the 1st variant shouldn't be there?

Comment: Good catch. Thanks - fixed.